# How to inspect a nodejs class in interactive mode?

Tags: node.js

I am testing some nodejs classes and using the node modules dir for details. But it would be easier to inspect. Below is the example. It does not display all the methods. Is just states -

> '[class Wallet]'

Is there a way to show the methods and more class details?

```
~/node_modules$ node
Welcome to Node.js v12.18.3.
Type ".help" for more information.
> const x=require('fabric-network')
undefined
> x
{
  Gateway: [class Gateway],
  Wallet: [class Wallet],
  Wallets: [class Wallets],
  IdentityProviderRegistry: [class IdentityProviderRegistry],
  HsmX509Provider: [class HsmX509Provider],
  DefaultCheckpointers: [class DefaultCheckpointers],
  DefaultEventHandlerStrategies: {
    MSPID_SCOPE_ALLFORTX: [Function],
    MSPID_SCOPE_ANYFORTX: [Function],
    NETWORK_SCOPE_ALLFORTX: [Function],
    NETWORK_SCOPE_ANYFORTX: [Function],
    NONE: [Function]
  },
  DefaultQueryHandlerStrategies: {
    MSPID_SCOPE_SINGLE: [Function],
    MSPID_SCOPE_ROUND_ROBIN: [Function]
  },
  TimeoutError: [class TimeoutError extends FabricError]
}

> x.Wallet
[class Wallet]
> util.inspect(x.Wallet)
'[class Wallet]'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `util` module and `inspect` method to dive into an object methods and classes. Here I set `showHidden` to true, `depth` to 1 and `color` to true.If depth sets to `null` will cause it to recurse 'all the way', showing every level. It will return colorful string as following.

```
const x = require('fabric-network');
const util = require('util');
console.log(util.inspect(x, true, 10, true))
```

output

```
 {
  Gateway: [Function: Gateway] {
    [length]: 0,
    [prototype]: [Gateway],
    [name]: 'Gateway'
  },
  Wallet: [Function: Wallet] {
    [length]: 1,
    [prototype]: [Wallet],
    [name]: 'Wallet'
  },
  Wallets: [Function: Wallets] {
    [length]: 0,
    [prototype]: [Wallets],
    [newInMemoryWallet]: [AsyncFunction],
    [newFileSystemWallet]: [AsyncFunction],
    [newCouchDBWallet]: [AsyncFunction],
    [name]: 'Wallets'
  },
  IdentityProviderRegistry: [Function: IdentityProviderRegistry] {
    [length]: 0,
    [prototype]: [IdentityProviderRegistry],
    [name]: 'IdentityProviderRegistry'
  },
  HsmX509Provider: [Function: HsmX509Provider] {
    [length]: 0,
    [prototype]: [HsmX509Provider],
    [name]: 'HsmX509Provider'
  },
  DefaultCheckpointers: [Function: DefaultCheckpointers] {
    [length]: 0,
    [prototype]: [DefaultCheckpointers],
    [file]: [AsyncFunction],
    [name]: 'DefaultCheckpointers'
  },
  DefaultEventHandlerStrategies: {
    [__esModule]: true,
    MSPID_SCOPE_ALLFORTX: [Function],
    MSPID_SCOPE_ANYFORTX: [Function],
    NETWORK_SCOPE_ALLFORTX: [Function],
    NETWORK_SCOPE_ANYFORTX: [Function],
    NONE: [Function]
  },
  DefaultQueryHandlerStrategies: {
    [__esModule]: true,
    MSPID_SCOPE_SINGLE: [Function],
    MSPID_SCOPE_ROUND_ROBIN: [Function]
  },
  TimeoutError: [Function: TimeoutError] {
    [length]: 1,
    [prototype]: [TimeoutError],
    [name]: 'TimeoutError',
    stackTraceLimit: 10
  }
}
```

Comment: Good info in your answer.